# Using azure devops to deploy to an offline server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using azure devops pipeline to build my IIS application and deploy via release management to several different servers, and it works great.  My issue though is that one of the servers I need to deploy to will always be offline, so I need to set up some sort of offline installer for that deployment.  Is there a way to do this using the build and release management I already have that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Pipelines assumes that the server is always available. Best I can think of is to generate some kind of drop on a fileshare and then add a Manual Intervention Task to pause the pipeline and allow you to do your thing.

There is no air-gapped agent nor a way to run part of your pipeline on another system and import the results.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something that would bundle my release tasks and run then as if they were one of my deployment servers.  Zip up my artifact and build the IIS site, deploy the dacpac, run the powershell.  Ideally I could bundle my variables with the offline deploy.  I guess I'm looking for something that would transform the release into a custom installer

Comment: Octopus Deploy has such features. Azure Pipelines unfortunately not.

Comment: Add your thoughts on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html so the product team can evaluate them.